# Delete duplicate pairs in mysql table

Tags: mysql

```
+------+---------+---------+
| id   | user_id | job_id  |
+------+---------+---------+
|   92 |      58 |       4 |
|  896 |      58 |       4 |
|  988 |      58 |      22 |
|  991 |      58 |      22 |
|  894 |      58 |      38 |
|  548 |      58 |      38 |
```

I want to delete the entries where the user_id has the same job_id duplicated. In other words there should only be one distinct job_id associated with the user_id. In this example there should only be 4,22,38 (and not duplicate entries). It doesn't matter which id is affected, as long as only one job_id is matched up against a user_id.

Comment: ALTER IGNORE TABLE t ADD UNIQUE KEY(user_id ,job_id  )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
DELETE t1 FROM tab t1, tab t2
WHERE  t1.id < t2.id
  AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id
  AND t1.job_id = t2.job_id;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66510/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦══════════╦════════╗
║ id   ║ user_id  ║ job_id ║
╠══════╬══════════╬════════╣
║ 896  ║      58  ║      4 ║
║ 991  ║      58  ║     22 ║
║ 894  ║      58  ║     38 ║
╚══════╩══════════╩════════╝
```

And consider adding `UNIQUE INDEX` on columns `user_id` and `job_id` to avoid this problem in future.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `left join`:

```
delete t
    from t left join
         (select min(id) as minid
          from t
          group by user_id, job_id
         ) tt
         on t.id = tt.minid
    where tt.minid is null;
```